# Clearing a Session variable after leaving a page

Tags: php

I've been thinking about this for a while and I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me figure this out.

I have a website, www.domain.com/page that I'm working on. The page also has the ability of having page;var=whatever at the end.

I'm trying to limit how many $_POST/$_REQUEST variables I need. Is there any way to keep a session variable active only while I'm on /page so that if a user goes to /page;var=whatever the session variable is still around but not if they go to /anotherPage?

Thanks!

Comment: Not a clear question.

Comment: Use _named sessions_.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be this:

```
session_start();

$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if (isset($_SESSION['page']) && $_SESSION['page'] != $uri['path']) {
    // We went to a new page
    unset($_SESSION['var']);
}

// Remember our current page.
$_SESSION['page'] = $uri['path'];
```